# Find to cells in range with specific colors and add comments

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will search a column of text (A:A) for a specific interior color. In this case the interior color is 55. Normally I'd create a range of `A1:A101` but the data that is added changes daily so there may be more or less.

Essentially once the macro identifies the cells with the colors I want the macro to add a comment to the cell. Something simple like "Hello World!".

So far this is what I have:

```
Sub AddCommentBasedOnColor()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("G:G")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 55 Then
        If rng.Comment Is Nothing Then rng.AddComment
        rng.Comment.Text "Possible Aux Stacking"
        End
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

The problem that I am running into is that when I am running the code, the comment portion does not work at all. No comments are made and for some reason I get a debug code but did not have one before. Not sure what I did that changed it.

Additionally, when I remove the commenting section of this code it does take some time to run, any assistance with shortening that length of time would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has logical problems.

With `rng.AddComment` you try setting a comment to the whole column G as `rng` is the whole column G. This is not possible.

And your inner `If` statement works as follows:

```
...
If rng.Comment Is Nothing Then rng.AddComment
rng.Comment.Text "Possible Aux Stacking"
End
...
```

If `rng.Comment` Is Nothing Then `rng.AddComment`. Here the `If` ends. The next program row is processing ever without additional conditions and the `End` then ends the Sub at this point.

To shortening the processing time you have not to run over all rows in column G. This is possible by calculation the last used row. How to do this differs on how you define the last used row. Since you are working with the cell's interior, I have defined the last used row as the last row having cells with not default content of empty cells.

```
Sub AddCommentBasedOnColor()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, lastUsedRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastUsedRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Set rng = .Range("G1:G" & lastUsedRow)

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 55 Then
            If cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                cell.AddComment
                cell.Comment.Text "Possible Aux Stacking"
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @shA.t: Can you please explain the need of your editing? I liked my indents as they were ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Find` rather than loop through each cell:

```
Sub AddCommentBasedOnColor()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim strFirst As String

Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 55

Set rng1 = Columns("G:G").Find(What:="", SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    strFirst = rng1.Address
    Set rng2 = rng1
        Do
            Set rng2 = Columns("G:G").Find(What:="", After:=rng2, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True)
            If rng2.Comment Is Nothing Then
                rng2.AddComment
                rng2.Comment.Text "Possible Aux Stacking"
            End If
        Loop Until rng2.Address = strFirst
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why use find rather than loop?

Comment: Efficiency - why look at every cell in a range rather than lick out the ones that matter.